# Multiple line renderers, each following a different object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I would like for help with my code. My goal is to have different line renders(max 4 ) follow players that enter a specific area defined by an overlap sphere. I would like for the lines to pop up only when the players enter the area and go away when the players are gone. I tried 4 different approaches but got nowhere please help. Thank you

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Transmission : MonoBehaviour
{
    private LineRenderer lr;
    private LineRenderer lr2;
    private LineRenderer lr3;
    private LineRenderer lr4;

    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float fieldofview = 20;
    Collider[] UsersInsideZone;
    public List<LineRenderer> lines;
    private Transform goTransform;
    private Ray ray;
    RaycastHit hit;
    int current;
    int count;
    public int Numberof5Gusers;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        lr = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lr2 = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lr3 = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        lr4 = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();

        lines = new List<LineRenderer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //Creating A zone where the 5G connection works in
        int playerMask = LayerMask.NameToLayer("player");
        int layer = (1 << playerMask);
        UsersInsideZone = Physics.OverlapSphere(rb.transform.position, fieldofview, layer);

        int amountofplayers = UsersInsideZone.Length;

        //for(int i = 0; i > UsersInsideZone.Length; i++)
        // {
        //    vertices[i] = UsersInsideZone[i].gameObject.transform.position;
        //     Instantiate(lr);
        //     lr.SetPosition(0, rb.transform.position);
        //      lr.SetPosition(1, UsersInsideZone[i].gameObject.transform.position);
        //  }

        // drawing a ray for each user in the zone 

        foreach (Collider player in UsersInsideZone)
        {
            // ALOT OF BEAMS THAT ARE PINK

            //if (!player.GetComponent<LineRenderer>())
            /// {
            //   player.gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
            //Destroy(player.GetComponent<LineRenderer>());

            // DrawBeam(player.transform.position, this.transform.position, Numberof5Gusers);

            // if (player.transform.position.magnitude - rb.transform.position.magnitude > fieldofview)
            // {
            //    Debug.Log("fdsafsa0");

            //  Destroy(player.GetComponent<LineRenderer>());
            // }
            //  }

            //One beam that doesnt follow more than one object
            for (int j = 0; j < UsersInsideZone.Length; j++)
            {
                lr.SetPosition(0, rb.transform.position);
                lr.SetPosition(1, UsersInsideZone[j].gameObject.transform.position);
            }

            // test white lines 
            Debug.DrawRay(rb.transform.position, player.transform.position, Color.green);
        }
    }

    void DrawBeam(Vector3 position, Vector3 start, int count)
    {
        LineRenderer lrend = new GameObject().AddComponent<LineRenderer>() as LineRenderer;
        lrend.SetPosition(0, start);
        lrend.SetPosition(1, position);
    }

    //RAYCASTING APPROACH 
    //   Vector3 target = player.transform.position;

    // RaycastHit hit1;
    // Vector3 end = rb.transform.position + (25 * player.transform.position);
    // if (!player.GetComponent<LineRenderer>())
    // {

    // lr.SetPosition(0, rb.transform.position);
    //   Ray ray = new Ray(rb.transform.position, player.transform.position);

    //  if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit1, layer))
    //  {
    //    if (hit1.collider)
    //    {

    //       lr.SetPosition(1, hit1.point);
    //    }
    //    if(hit1.collider.transform.position.magnitude> fieldofview)
    //    {
    //         Destroy(lr);
    //         lr.SetPosition(1, rb.transform.position);
    //    }
    //}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can not have multiple `Renderers` attached to the same `GameObject`.

So I would rather simply spawn 4 empty child objects with those components attached to them like

```
void Start()
{
    lr = new GameObject().AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    lr.gameObject.SetParent(transform, false);
    // just to be sure reset position and rotation as well
    lr.gameObject.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);

    lr2 = new GameObject().AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    lr2.gameObject.SetParent(transform, false);
    // just to be sure reset position and rotation as well
    lr2.gameObject.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);

    lr3 = new GameObject().AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    lr3.gameObject.SetParent(transform, false);
    // just to be sure reset position and rotation as well
    lr3.gameObject.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);

    lr4 = new GameObject().AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
    lr4.gameObject.SetParent(transform, false);
    // just to be sure reset position and rotation as well
    lr4.gameObject.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Easier would be if you create one prefab from an empty GameObjet with a `LinerRenderer` and do e.g.

```
LineRenderer linePrefab;

void Start()
{
    lr = Instantiate(linePrefab, transform);
    lr2 = Instantiate(linePrefab, transform);
    lr3 = Instantiate(linePrefab, transform);
    lr4 = Instantiate(linePrefab, transform);

    //...
}
```

or ... why not already create that structure in the editor? Than you wouldn't have to do it by script at all ...

---

You never fill your List `lines` (actually you wouldn't even need the single variables)

```
lines = new List<LineRenderer>();

lines.Add(lr);
lines.Add(lr2);
lines.Add(lr3);
lines.Add(lr4);
```

and

> // ALOT OF BEAMS THAT ARE PINK

You have to assign a `Material` to the `LineRenderer`s e.g. like

```
public Material lineMaterial;

void Start()
{
    // ...

    // set material
    foreach(var line in lines)
    {
        line.material = lineMaterial;

        // could also give them colors
        //line.material.color = someColor;
    }
}
```

---

Now to the check in `Update()`

```
// ...

// run through all available lines
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
{
    var currentLine = lines[i];

    // if under player count -> set enabled and set positions
    if(i < amountofplayers)
    {
        currentLine.enabled = true;

        // set target to player at same index as this line
        currentLine.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
        currentLine.SetPosition(1, UsersInsideZone[i].gameObject.transform.position);
    }

    // otherwise set disabled
    else   
    {
        currentLine.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

---

**Note**: I would still not do this `Physics.OverlapSphere` since first it costs performance and second it might not return the players always in the same order.

I would rather do something like

```
private List<Collider> UsersInsideZone = new List<Collider>();

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    // you would give them tags instead of a layer
    if(col.gameObject.tag != "player") return;

    // or alternative set which layers can collide at all in the Physics settings

    if(UsersInsideZone.Contains(col)) return;

    UsersInsideZone.Add(col);
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
{
    // you would give them tags instead of a layer
    if(col.gameObject.tag != "player") return;

    // or alternative set which layers can collide at all in the Physics settings

    if(!UsersInsideZone.Contains(col)) return;

    UsersInsideZone.Remove(col);
}

private void Update()
{
    // run through all available lines
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
    {
        var currentLine = lines[i];

        // if under player count -> set enabled and set positions
        if(i < amountofplayers)
        {
            currentLine.enabled = true;

            // set target to player at same index as this line
            currentLine.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
            currentLine.SetPosition(1, UsersInsideZone[i].gameObject.transform.position);
        }

        // otherwise set disabled
        else   
        {
            currentLine.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your detailed answer, I am running the code right now and no beams show up, I believe it has to to with this line in the update method   currentLine.SetPosition(1, UsersInsideZone[i].gameObject.transform.position);  The reason being  is that the onTrigger methods work but you don't connect it to the update method which makes the above line show an error of index out of range

Comment: Sorry The issue was you wrote "player" tag when it actually should be Player thanks for the help